# Python Login to Yahoo using requests or mechanize

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize, python-requests

I want to send login information to yahoo through python and determine whether the login was successful or not. I have looked around a lot of questions on StackOverflow dealing with this topic and have yet to find a valid, updated answer. So far here are my attempts:

Attempt 1:
In this attempt, I used the python requests library as well as BeautifulSoup to parse the resulting file. Below is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

login = { 
    'login-username' : username,
    'login-passwd' : password }

with requests.Session() as s:
    con = s.post('http://login.yahoo.com', data=login)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(con.text)
    print soup.get_text()
```

with username and password containing my actual information as a string. The reason I chose 'login-username' and 'login-passwd' is that those represent the ids of the input form. I am pretty sure to use this instead of the name values of the input form. The problem with this approach is that I always have an error saying invalid id or password even though the correct credentials are inputted.

Attempt 2: In this attempt, I decided to use mechanize and the people around StackOverflow suggested the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response = br.open("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us")

#assert br.viewing_html()
print response.get_data()
br.select_form(nr=0)

br["login"] = username
br["passwd"] = password

response = br.submit()
print response.get_data()
```

Now the problem with the code is that I receive the following error: **mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'login'**.
When this happened, I tried variations of the control matching name like br['login-username'] and such but nothing worked. I am guessing that the problem has to do something with me selecting the forms but I am not quite sure.

I hope I provided enough information to indicate where the problem exists. I spent a couple hours today searching around and trying to figure it out so I am really desperate for help.

Comment: the name is username not login, try `br.form["username"]= ... br.form["passwd"] = ... `

Comment: if you use `for f in br.forms():print f` it will show you the available forms

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Just curious, do you happen to know what is wrong with my first attempt?

Comment: did you try using `'username' : "..."` and 'passwd' : "..."?

Comment: I actually tried that but I get a message that says the browser you are using refuses to sign in (cookies rejected).

Comment: the field names are correct as the as you can see fron the `#mbr-login-form` field names`{'username': '', '_ts': '1419012689', 'passwd': None, '_format': '', '_uuid': 'oqbgOxYbGlvy', '.persistent': None, '_seqid': '2', '_crumb': ''}`, not sure what is happening in regard to the cookies.